# WSO2 and Linux High Availability

Tags: wso2, rhel, high-availability

Does anyone have information on how to manage WSO2 products using RHEL High Availability Addon? WSO2 don't provide any information on this.
I think installation of WSO2 products as web-applications on tomcat6 is last thing I shold do and there should be another solution.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Products can make use of standard High Availability options.

For example, We have a guide on [ELB Automatic Failover](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ELB210/Automatic+Failover).

In addition, the WSO2 products support to run in clustered environments and we have the [clustering and deployment guides for WSO2 products](https://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/WSO2+Clustering+and+Deployment+Guide) in our wiki.

You should never run WSO2 products as web applications as we no longer recommended to run WSO2 products in another container.

This is a just a quick answer. Please ask if you have further questions.